# admin-ajax.php - the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've drawn a complete blank with this if anyone can help. I have migrated a website from from a NGINX server to Apache. The installation works fine on NGINX but am running in to the following issue since the migration.

This is a WordPress installation, version 4.9.5 on an Apache server with PHP 7.2

I am constantly getting an error when trying to publish theme customisations.

```
Looks like something’s gone wrong. Wait a couple of seconds, and then try again.
```

The console shows the following error for file /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have taken the following troubleshooting steps to no avail -

- Increased memory and size limits to 256M
- Downgraded to PHP 7.0
- Reinstalled core files in /wp-admin and /wp-includes
- Removed .htaccess in case of corruption
- Confirmed no PHP errors using WP_DEBUG (true)
- Confirmed file permissions are as they should be
- Deactivated any non essential plugins.

Comment: This is most likely PHP error though. What are the values of `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`?